# Traverse tree in a functional way

Tags: algorithm, scala, data-structures, tree, functional-programming

I've implemented a basic mutable tree in Scala and I want to traverse it in a functional way in order to search for an element, but I don't know how to implement it. I want also the algorithm to be tail recursive if possible.

The tree is a structure with a value and a list of leafs that are also trees.

Any help would be appreciated.

This is the code that I have (focus on getOpt method):

```
package main

import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

sealed trait Tree[Node] {

  val node: Node

  val parent: Option[Tree[Node]]

  val children: ListBuffer[Tree[Node]]

  def add(n: Node): Tree[Node]

  def size: Int

  def getOpt(p: (Node) => Boolean): Option[Tree[Node]]

  override def toString = {
    s"""[$node${if (children.isEmpty) "" else s", Children: $children"}]"""
  }
}

case class ConcreteTree(override val node: Int) extends Tree[Int] {

  override val children = ListBuffer[Tree[Int]]()

  override val parent: Option[Tree[Int]] = None

  override def add(n: Int): ConcreteTree = {
    val newNode = new ConcreteTree(n) {override val parent: Option[Tree[Int]] = Some(this)}
    children += newNode
    newNode
  }

  override def size: Int = {
    def _size(t: Tree[Int]): Int = {
      1 + t.children.foldLeft(0)((sum, tree) => sum + _size(tree))
    }
    _size(this)
  }

  // This method is not correct
  override def getOpt(p: (Int) => Boolean): Option[Tree[Int]] = {
    def _getOpt(tree: Tree[Int], p: (Int) => Boolean): Option[Tree[Int]] = {
      tree.children.map {
        t =>
          if(p(t.node)) Some(t) else t.children.map(_getOpt(_, p))
      }
    }
  }
}

object Main {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val tree1 = ConcreteTree(1)
    val tree2 = tree1.add(2)
    val tree3 = tree1.add(3)

    println(tree1.getOpt(_ == 2))
  }
}
```

@doertsch answer is the best approach that I have at the moment.

Comment: a simple in-order traversal should do. Unless the tree is ordered

Comment: Have you tried writing any code?

Comment: @Archeg Yep, I know how to do it in an OOP way, but I don't know how to do it in a functional way. For example, a can't map on the list of leafs as I want to return an Option[Tree[_]] but it results on a ListBuffer[Option[Tree[_]]] and I also want to finish when a result is found.

Comment: @vicaba Then please post your code you've tried and we will try to help you fix the issues there.

Comment: @Archeg I have added the code.

Comment: @vicaba Your code doesn't seem compilable to me. You are missing first line of the class and `Node` definition. But @doertsch code seems a great fit into your code, so you can look at his code piece as a guidance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would actually go for something more flexible and implement a generic function to produce a lazy stream of your flattened tree, then a lot of your later work will become much easier.  Something like this:

```scala
def traverse[Node](tree: Tree[Node]): Stream[Tree[Node]] = 
  tree #:: (tree.children map traverse).fold(Stream.Empty)(_ ++ _)
```

Then your `getOpt` reduces to this:

```scala
override def getOpt(p: (Int) => Boolean): Option[Tree[Int]] =
  traverse(tree) find {x => p(x.node)}
```

Simplifying even further, if you're just interested in the data without the `Tree` structure, you can just get a stream of nodes, giving you:

```scala
def nodes[Node](tree: Tree[Node]): Stream[Node] = traverse(tree) map (_.node)

def getNode(p: (Int) => Boolean): Option[Int] = nodes(tree) find p
```

This opens other possibilities for very concise and readable code like `nodes(tree) filter (_ > 3)`, `nodes(tree).sum`, `nodes(tree) contains 12`, and similar expressions.

Comment: Hi Karl,

2 questions:
1. the return type of the traverse function seems to be Stream[Tree[_ <: RNComponent]] and not Stream[Tree[RNComponent]]

def traverse[RNComponent](tree: Tree[RNComponent]): Stream[Tree[_ <: RNComponent]] =
    tree #:: (tree.children map traverse).fold(Stream.Empty)(_ ++ _)

2. The ++ operator is not defined. the following does not work for me.

 def ++(t0: Tree[RNComponent], t1: Tree[RNComponent]): Stream[Tree[_ <: RNComponent]] =
    t0 #:: t1
  
Any tips? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using the methods `exists` and `find` (which every `List` provides), you can achieve the "finish when a result is found" behaviour. (Although it might be argued that internally, these are not implemented in a totally functional way: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/5adc400f5ece336f3f5ff19691204975d41e652e/src/library/scala/collection/LinearSeqOptimized.scala#L88)

Your code might look as follows:

```
case class Tree(nodeValue: Long, children: List[Tree]) {

  def containsValue(search: Long): Boolean =
    search == nodeValue || children.exists(_.containsValue(search))

  def findSubTreeWithNodeValue(search: Long): Option[Tree] =
    if (search == nodeValue)
      Some(this)
    else
      children.find(_.containsValue(search)).
        flatMap(_.findSubTreeWithNodeValue(search))
}
```

On the last two lines, the `find` application will return the correct subtree of the current node, in case one exists, and the `flatMap` part will extract the correct subtree from it recursively, or leave the `None` result unchanged if the value was not found.

This one, however, has the unlovely characteristic of doing parts of the traversal twice, once for determining whether a result exists, and once for extracting it from the tree that contains it. There might be a way to fix this in a more efficient way, but I can't figure it out at the moment ...

Comment: Thank you, I don't mark the answer as the solution so someone can come up with a "better" solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think, you are looking for something like this:

```
@tailrec
def findInTree[T](value: T, stack: List[Node[T]]): Option[Node[T]] = stack match {
   case Nil => None
   case Node(value) :: _ => stack.headOption
   case head :: tail => findInTree(value, head.children ++ tail)
}
```

This does not traverse parts of the tree twice, and is also tail-recursive.
I changed your class definitions a little bit for clarity, but it's the same idea. 
You call it something like this: `findInTree(valueToFind, List(root))`

Answer (score 1):

When turning a collection into a [view](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_42.html), all transformers like `map` are implemented lazily. This means elements are only processed as required. This should solve your problem:

```
override def getOpt(p: (Int) => Boolean): Option[Tree[Int]] = {
  if (p(node)) Some(this)
  else children.view.map(_.getOpt(p)).find(_.isDefined).getOrElse(None)
}
```

So we are mapping (lazily) over the children, turning them into `Option`s of the searched node. Subsequently we find the first such `Option` being not `None`. The final `getOrElse(None)` is required to "flatten" the nested Options since `find` returns an `Option` itself.

I didn't actually run the code, so please excuse minor mistakes. However, the general approach should have become clear.